# Python generate multiple random matrices in a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix, random

I am trying to generate 100 random column stochastic matrices using a for loop and save them.

Below code is to generate an individual random column stochastic matrix.

```py
import numpy as np
import random

For x in range(100):
    a = 2
    sto = np.identity(2)
    sto = sto + np.random.uniform(low=0.2, high=0.5, size=(a, a))
    sto = sto / sto.sum(axis=0, keepdims=1)
    print(sto)
```

<strike>When I try to implement the operation to generate 100 matrices with a for loop I fail - all matrices generated turn out to be the same.</strike>

Edit: I can now generate different matrices in the loop.

But I still don't know how to save them all to use in later work (for instance: saving them to multiply some of them at a later step)?

Comment: I don't see any for loop in your code. Could you show it?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it. I think I solved the problem with generating the same matrix over and over again: the ones generated now are different from each other. But I still have the problem with saving them.

Comment: Append them to a list.

Comment: I tried that. I basically fail, I generate distinct lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you expect as the outcome, but I don't think you need a for-loop.

Here is my solution:

```
a = 2
i = np.expand_dims(np.eye(a), 0)
x = np.random.uniform(low=0.2, high=0.5, size=(100, a, a))
s = i + x
out = s / np.expand_dims(s.sum(1), 1)
```

In fact, internally a 100-loop adds all values in matching dimensions of `i` and `x`. The trick is that `expand_dims` method creates a dummy dimension to be able to only have one mismatched dimension equal to 1. Then, these operations between two arrays are possible. The second `expand_dims` also has a similar role but on a different dimension. In the end, if you want it as a list, you can convert it to a list of 100 arrays:

```
out = list(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but basically i created a list named `sto1` so that you can access it in the later parts of your code

```
import numpy as np
import random

sto1 = []
for x in range(100):
    a = 2
    sto = np.identity(2)
    sto = sto + np.random.uniform(low=0.2, high=0.5, size=(a, a))
    sto = sto / sto.sum(axis=0, keepdims=1)
    sto1.append(sto)
print(sto1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save them on the hard-drive:

```py
import numpy as np

random_matrices = np.random.rand(100,2,2)

np.save('random_matrices.npy', random_matrices)

random_matrices_loaded = np.load('random_matrices.npy')
```